# How to turn on Processor ID of the computer in bios?

Tags: c#, settings, processor, bios

I am developing window application in C#. I have developed an installer which takes the processor ID of the computer & generates the unique key. My installer is running fine in almost all the computers but on one computer it is not able to read the processor ID. I debugged my program & I found that it has not the proper permissions to read the processor Id. Now I want to turn on the Processor ID in bios. Can you please tell me the step by step procedure of how to turn on Processor ID in bios ? Or Can you please provide me any link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Comment: Are you asking to turn it on programatically or through the BIOS boot setup pages?

Comment: If you provide me the solution through both the ways then it will help me a lot or if provide me the solution through any one way then it is also helpful

Comment: FYI, Intel implemented the PSN in the Pentium 3 only. It was discontinued for the P4 due to privacy concerns (and always returns all zeros). AMD never implemented it in any of their processors. So this is probably not very useful in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That largely depends on the particular BIOS. I doubt you'll get a reasonable answer for your question. However, generally you should look for a 'CPUID' Enable / Disable setting.